# testing strict validations in rails 3.2 with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

In rspec how do I test what attribute failed the strict validation. I have only been able to test if the "ActiveModel::StrictValidationFailed" exception was thrown.

Here is a example:

```
it "should not be valid if the asset already exists" do
     n = Factory.build( :private_attached_asset, :asset => Rack::Test::UploadedFile.new( "test.pdf", 'application/pdf' ))
     expect { n.save }.should raise_error(ActiveModel::StrictValidationFailed)
     #n.should have(1).error_on(:checksum)
 end
```

The commented out line throws the exception again.

Comment: Also, consider using `"is not valid..."` instead of `"should not be valid..."`. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't check for error messages on strict validations because they raise immediately and don't set the `errors` object. Alternatively, you can test the exact error message raised:

```
expect { n.valid? }.to raise_error(ActiveModel::StrictValidationFailed, 'Exact message thrown')
```